# How can I achieve this functionality?

Tags: 8, views

I am a new vibe drupal developer and I have created content type as an event which displays on home page upcoming event as blogs
i have created a simple blog event using view home page but I don't know how to achieve these using view or other modules. plz correct me if i am wrong thanks in advance

Expected result
when a user clicks these of any event it displays image and title description main square

| image | event title |
| --- | --- |
| One | event description |

title: 1 jan(Date)
description:event description

title: 2 jan(Date)
description:event description

title: 3 jan(Date)
description:event description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have already added the image and event description, etc. as fields for the event content type.

For custom content types, normally you control the display using the **Manage Display** link from Structure -> Content Types -> Edit.

You can rearrange the fields how you want in the UI, and you can also use a Twig theme template to customize the specific HTML.  Core also provides the Layout Builder module to make something more complex.

It's also possible to use Views to overwrite the default content page, but it is usually easier to use Twig templates and/or Layout Builder.  If you do want to use Views, take a look at the core Taxonomy Term display to see how Views can be used to override a path for a custom content type.

Comment: thank you for guide me. help me any other tutorial which i should read ?layout builder and view

Comment: If you don't know about the differences between Views and Layout Builder, it's probably good to read a whole book about Drupal, not just a tutorial: https://www.drupal.org/books

Comment: i am small knowlage about view.layout builder and view combine can i achive this?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, you don't need Views for this. You can use theme templates combined with fields to do this easily.